# Removing red cross in print composer?

Tags: printing, print-composer

My problem is with the print composer: it shows a huge red cross. I thought it is because of a wrong image format, because there was a smaller cross on one of the images. So I deleted it, then deleted all of the images I have used, but it is still there.

Can someone help me how to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no image left in the composer? you can check that via the "Items" box in the print composer as shown below. or maybe there is a missing picture locked in the items box?
[image]

Comment: I dont have this items box. i have composition, item properties and atlas generation as well but items is missing.